# jQuery's Select2 is dulicated

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

hope that you're doing well, as for my problem, I want to use a Select2 jQuery plugin's drop-down menu, I copied the code directly from another page that is working fine, but it showing me the drop-down menu duplicated I tried all that I thought it could help but they all failled, here what I did:

**HTML: (the whole div)**

```
<div class="form-group row student" bis_skin_checked="1" data-select2-id="15">
                                    <label for="lname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Class Name</label>                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select class="select2 form-control custom-select select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%; height:36px;" data-select2-id="2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required="" name="class">
                                            <option data-select2-id="4">Select</option>
                                            <optgroup label="Administrateur des systèmes réseaux">
                                                <option value="ASR#21-S2">ASR#21-S2</option>
                                                <option value="ASR#20-S4">ASR#20-S4</option>
                                            </optgroup>
                                            <optgroup label="Génie de l’environnement">
                                                <option value="GE#20-S2">GE#20-S4</option>
                                                <option value="GE#21-S2">GE#21-S2</option>
                                                <option value="GE#19-S6">GE#19-S6</option>
                                            </optgroup>
                                            <optgroup label="Métiers du social et de l'Animation socioculturelle">
                                                <option value="MSASC#21-S2">MSASC#21-S2</option>
                                                <option value="MSASC#20-S4">MSASC#20-S4</option>
                                            </optgroup>
                                            <optgroup label="Développement des territoires ruraux">
                                                <option value="DTR#21-S2">DTR#21-S2</option>
                                                <option value="DTR#21-S2">DTR#20-S4</option>
                                            </optgroup>
                                            <optgroup label="Bioanalyses et contrôle">
                                                <option value="BIOAC#21-S2">BIOAC#21-S2</option>
                                                <option value="BIOAC#20-S4">BIOAC#20-S4</option>
                                            </optgroup>
                                        </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="3" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ8fs.png)

As for the libraries and css they are imported

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/a/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/a/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
                //***********************************//
                // For select 2
                //***********************************//
                $(".select2").select2();
</script>
```

Thank you for your help, really I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! What I did is going to the added unused span and changed the class from "select2" to "select3" and it disapeared
**FROM**  select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus
**TO** select3 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus